# why is this StringBuilder code not giving the desired output

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I want to compress the string using `StringBuilder` but the code is not working as expected. It is simply returning the print statement.

```
import java.util.*;
public class string_compression {

    public static String compress(String str){

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");

        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            Integer count =0;
            while(i<str.length()-1 && str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(i+1)){
                count++;
                i++;
            }
            sb=sb.append(str.charAt(i));
            if(count>1){
                sb = sb.append(str.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your string: ");
        String str = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Compressed string is : ");
        System.out.println(compress(str));
        sc.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You never do anything with the value returned by `compress` (print it, or even store it in a variable).

Comment: Print it like System.out.println("Compressed string is : " + compress(str));

You are not printing result currently.

Comment: I have updated the code. I figured that out but still, the number count ain't printing.

Comment: I got it, the Integer count = 0 should be changed to Integer count =1. I was taking it 0 = even when it was 1 thus creating fuss at the output